# CQ DAM Media Handler

Tags: aem

I am new to CQ and have a question specific to CQ DAM Media handler. We have a requirement to generate the thumbnail for the camera raw formats files. I took the reference of below adobe document and installed imagemagicka :

> http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/wem/dam/dam_media_handlers.html
>   (Command Line Based Media Handler)

I am able to run the tool as mentioned in the step from command line, but when i am editing the "Dam Update Asset" model then its not working and getting "ABORTED" message in archive with below error detail :

```
*Forbidden
Cannot serve request to /content/dam/media/1.gif/_jcr_content/metadata/ in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
Request Progress:
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/content/dam/media/1.gif/_jcr_content/metadata/
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/content/dam/media/1.gif/_jcr_content/metadata/ resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/content/dam/media/1.gif/jcr:content/metadata
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/dam/media/1.gif/jcr:content/metadata', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='/'
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/content/dam/media/1.gif/jcr:content/metadata)}
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/content/dam/media/1.gif/jcr:content/metadata)} Using servlet org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/content/dam/media/1.gif/_jcr_content/metadata/ handled by Servlet=org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter
      0 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (request extension does not match)
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Applying Componentfilters
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_START{org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet#0}
      1 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Using org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.helpers.StreamRendererServlet to render for extension=null
      2 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Applying Error filters
      2 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      2 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_START{handleError:status=403}
      2 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_END{0,handleError:status=403} Using handler /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/default.jsp
     97 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html],order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=node /libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobile, values={component-optional=true, jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured}]), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=node /libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobiledebug, values={component-optional=true, jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured}]), Config(type=contentsync, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=node /libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-contentsync, values={component-optional=true, jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured}]), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
     97 (2013-08-13 09:27:33) TIMER_END{97,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ! I found the root cause of this issue. I was able to run command line tool. Point to remember : Provide the complete path of convert command (/opt/local/bin/convert) instead of just convert and second is to use command line workflow component instead of process workflow component.

Answer (score 0):

"Forbidden" sounds like there is a permissions issue.

CQ5 has fine-grained permissions on a given path.  The user may have permissions to create, but not edit (or vice-versa) or even only read, or not even read.

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/security.html

Alternately, there are other logs on the server that may show more details:

```
${CQ_HOME}/crx-quickstart/logs/error.log
```